# How to set all tensors to cuda device?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

The project needed to calculate on the GPU, but manually switching each tensor .to(device) is too long.

I used this, but the tensors still remain on the cpu. [pic with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS9T9.png)

```py
if torch.cuda.is_available():
     torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer has a mistake in the method name, it should be:

```
#instead of:
torch.set_default_tensor_type(device)
#should be:
torch.set_default_device(device)
```

I arranged it into a nice form in order to fallback to cpu or to the first cuda device.

```
device = torch.device(
                      f'cuda:{torch.cuda.current_device()}')
                      if torch.cuda.is_available()
                      else 'cpu'

torch.set_default_device(self.device)
```

That way you are covered if the machine has no GPU available.

Answer (score 0):

To set all tensors to a CUDA device, you can use the 'to' method of the 'torch' tensor library. The to method allows you to specify the device that you want to move the tensor 'to'. For example, to move all tensors to the first CUDA device, you can use the following code:

```
    import torch

# Set all tensors to the first CUDA device
device = torch.device("cuda:0")
torch.set_default_tensor_type(device)
```

Alternatively, you can also specify the device when you create a new tensor using the 'device' argument. For example:

```
import torch

# Set all tensors to the first CUDA device
device = torch.device("cuda:0")
x = torch.zeros(10, device=device)
```

This will create a tensor 'x' on the first CUDA device.